# Powershell not loading CSV values

Tags: powershell

I wonder if someone can give me some guidance on a power shell script as i'm new to it.

I have been tasked with renaming some machines that are not domain joined and so I have written the below, to do this from a CSV.

```
# MASTER SCRIPT TO RENAME REMOTE
$CSV = Import-Csv "C:\test1\rename.CSV"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $CSV.ComputerName -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock {
    Rename-Computer -ComputerName $CSV.ComputerName -NewName $CSV.NewName -Force
    Restart-Computer -force -Credential Admin 
    Write-Host "Please wait while computer restarts" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
}
```

The script prompts me for the admin password, and then returned the error "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'". I know the value (an IP address) is correct.

The CSV value header is correctly names as "ComputerName" and the file path is correct. The machine restarts as requested in the script correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop over the lines in the .CSV.

Something like this should do it:

```
$CSV = Import-Csv "C:\test1\rename.CSV"
$CSV |Foreach-Object {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Using:_.ComputerName -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock {
        Rename-Computer -ComputerName $Using:_.ComputerName -NewName $Using:_.NewName -Force
        Restart-Computer -force -Credential Admin 
        Write-Host "Please wait while computer restarts" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
    }
}
```

Comment: `$_.ComputerName`,`$_.NewName` are local variables; the script block is executed remotely. Either pass an `-ArgumentList`/`-Args` to the script block or use `$using:varname`

Comment: Great, thankyou both for the assistance